# PHP equivalent to JavaScript's string split method

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working with this on JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sURL = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/accenture-application-for/id415321306?uo=2&mt=8&uo=2";
    splitURL = sURL.split('/');
    var appID = splitURL[splitURL.length - 1].match(/[0-9]*[0-9]/)[0];
    document.write('<br /><strong>Link Lookup:</strong> <a href="http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsLookup?id=' + appID + '&country=es" >Lookup</a><br />');
</script>
```

This script takes the numeric ID and gives me 415321306.

So my question is how can I do the same thing but using PHP.

Best regards.

Answer (score 12):

Use PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function instead of .split().

```
splitURL = sURL.split('/');  //JavaScript
```

becomes

```
$splitURL = explode('/', $sURL);  //PHP
```

An use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of .match().

```
$appID = preg_match("[0-9]*[0-9]", $splitURL);
```

I'm a little unclear on what you're doing with the length of the string, but you can get substrings in php with [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: your `$appID` will be an int that's either 0 or 1 [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Thanks, @jnpcl - I fixed the typo.  @kjy112, I just repeated the regex that @m4k00 used.

Answer (score 5):

Who needs regex?

```
<?php
    $sURL = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/accenture-application-for/id415321306?uo=2&mt=8&uo=2";
    $appID = str_replace('id','',basename(parse_url($sURL, PHP_URL_PATH)));
    echo $appID; // output: 415321306
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match("/([0-9]+)/",$url,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

The two functions you desire are:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Javascript split can also be used to convert a string into a character array (empty argument) and the first argument can be a RegExp.

```
/*

Example 1

This can be done with php function str_split();

*/

var str = "Hello World!"

str.split('');

H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d,!

/*

Example 1

This can be done with php function preg_split();

*/

var str = " \u00a0\n\r\t\f\u000b\u200b";

str.split('');

, , , , ,,,​
```

> **From Ecma-262**
>   Returns  an  Array  object  into  which  substrings  of  the  result 
>   of  converting  this  object  to  a  String  have  been  stored.  The 
>   substrings  are  determined  by  searching  from  left  to  right  for
>   occurrences  of  separator;  these  occurrences are not part of any
>   substring in the returned array, but serve to divide up the String
>   value. The  value of  separator  may be a String of any length or it
>   may be a RegExp object (i.e., an object whose [[Class]]  internal
>   property is "RegExp"; see 15.10). The value of separator may be an
>   empty String, an empty regular expression, or a regular expression
>   that can  match an empty String. In this case,  separator  does not
>   match the empty substring at the beginning or end of  the  input 
>   String,  nor  does  it  match  the  empty  substring  at  the  end  of
>   the  previous  separator  match.  (For  example, if separator is the
>   empty String, the String is split up into individual characters; the
>   length of the result  array  equals  the  length  of  the  String, 
>   and  each  substring  contains  one  character.)  If  separator  is  a
>   regular  expression, only the first match at a given position of the 
>   this  String is considered, even if backtracking could  yield  a 
>   non-empty-substring  match  at  that  position.  (For  example, 
>   "ab".split(/a*?/)  evaluates  to  the  array ["a","b"], while
>   "ab".split(/a*/) evaluates to the array["","b"].) If the  this  object
>   is (or converts to) the empty String, the result depends on whether 
>   separator  can match the  empty String. If it can, the result array
>   contains no elements. Otherwise, the result array contains one
>   element,  which is the empty String. If  separator  is a regular
>   expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time 
>   separator  is matched  the results (including any  undefined  results)
>   of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

Answer (score 0):

javascript equivalent functions to php
(http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)

```
<script>
  function preg_split (pattern, subject, limit, flags) {
        // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
        // + original by: Marco Marchi??
        // * example 1: preg_split(/[\s,]+/, 'hypertext language, programming');
        // * returns 1: ['hypertext', 'language', 'programming']
        // * example 2: preg_split('//', 'string', -1, 'PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY');
        // * returns 2: ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
        // * example 3: var str = 'hypertext language programming';
        // * example 3: preg_split('/ /', str, -1, 'PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE');
        // * returns 3: [['hypertext', 0], ['language', 10], ['programming', 19]]
        // * example 4: preg_split('/( )/', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8', 4, 'PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE');
        // * returns 4: ['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4 5 6 7 8']
        // * example 5: preg_split('/( )/', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8', 4, (2 | 4));
        // * returns 5: [['1', 0], [' ', 1], ['2', 2], [' ', 3], ['3', 4], [' ', 5], ['4 5 6 7 8', 6]]
    
        limit = limit || 0; flags = flags || ''; // Limit and flags are optional
    
        var result, ret=[], index=0, i = 0,
            noEmpty = false, delim = false, offset = false,
            OPTS = {}, optTemp = 0,
            regexpBody = /^\/(.*)\/\w*$/.exec(pattern.toString())[1],
            regexpFlags = /^\/.*\/(\w*)$/.exec(pattern.toString())[1];
            // Non-global regexp causes an infinite loop when executing the while,
            // so if it's not global, copy the regexp and add the "g" modifier.
            pattern = pattern.global && typeof pattern !== 'string' ? pattern :
                new RegExp(regexpBody, regexpFlags+(regexpFlags.indexOf('g') !==-1 ? '' :'g'));
    
        OPTS = {
            'PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY': 1,
            'PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE': 2,
            'PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE': 4
        };
        if (typeof flags !== 'number') { // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags
            flags = [].concat(flags);
            for (i=0; i < flags.length; i++) {
                // Resolve string input to bitwise e.g. 'PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE' becomes 4
                if (OPTS[flags[i]]) {
                    optTemp = optTemp | OPTS[flags[i]];
                }
            }
            flags = optTemp;
        }
        noEmpty = flags & OPTS.PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY;
        delim = flags & OPTS.PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE;
        offset = flags & OPTS.PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE;
    
        var _filter = function(str, strindex) {
            // If the match is empty and the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY flag is set don't add it
            if (noEmpty && !str.length) {return;}
            // If the PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag is set
            //      transform the match into an array and add the index at position 1
            if (offset) {str = [str, strindex];}
            ret.push(str);
        };
        // Special case for empty regexp
        if (!regexpBody){
            result=subject.split('');
            for (i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
                _filter(result[i], i);
            }
            return ret;
        }
        // Exec the pattern and get the result
        while (result = pattern.exec(subject)) {
            // Stop if the limit is 1
            if (limit === 1) {break;}
            // Take the correct portion of the string and filter the match
            _filter(subject.slice(index, result.index), index);
            index = result.index+result[0].length;
            // If the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag is set, every capture match must be included in the results array
            if (delim) {
                // Convert the regexp result into a normal array
                var resarr = Array.prototype.slice.call(result);
                for (i = 1; i < resarr.length; i++) {
                    if (result[i] !== undefined) {
                        _filter(result[i], result.index+result[0].indexOf(result[i]));
                    }
                }
            }
            limit--;
        }
        // Filter last match
        _filter(subject.slice(index, subject.length), index);
        return ret;
    }
   </script>
```